# angular ng-repeat track by $index

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-directive

I'm having some trouble understanding why if I use track by Index in a ng-repeat, after removing a item from a array I get the "wrong" values in the scope of a directive.

As you can see in the below plunker if I remove the first Item in the array tracked by index, the value in the directive scope will not be the initial one.

I was expecting to have after the removal:
2 - b
3 - c

but I get 
2 - a
3 - b

If I don't use track by index I get the right values.

This is the Script

```
nsTests.controller('nsTestCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$filter', '$timeout',
function ($rootScope, $scope, $filter, $timeout) {

    $scope.data = [
     {
         id: 1,
         name: 'a'
     },
     {
         id: 2,
         name: 'b'
     },
     {
         id: 3,
         name: 'c'
     },
    ];

    $scope.data2 = [
     {
         id: 1,
         name: 'a'
     },
     {
         id: 2,
         name: 'b'
     },
     {
         id: 3,
         name: 'c'
     },
    ];

    $scope.removeByIndex = function (index) {
        $scope.data.splice(index, 1);            
    }

    $scope.removeByItem = function (item) {
        var index = $scope.data2.indexOf(item);
        if (index !== -1) {
            $scope.data2.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
}
]);


nsTests.directive('test', function ($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '{{value}}',
    scope: {
        data: '='
    },
    controller: function ($scope) {
        $scope.value = $scope.data.name;            
    }
};
});
```

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LX3wh7BwLJehLwfEwttG?p=preview) with the problem

Comment: This seems to be some buggy behaviour with your directive. If you log your actual data arrays you see that the array is actually just 'b' and 'c' left, yet your directive keeps displaying 'a'

Comment: I believe angular does not properly detect the value change for the directive through dirty checking, so you have to make other checks

Answer (score 1):

I think my [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/jTBuELnunnj1zCfPbah6?p=preview) and explanation will help you to understand these thing better way.

Here issue is not with the `track by $index`

```
nsTests.directive('test', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '{{value}}',
        scope: {
            data: '='
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.value = $scope.data.name;            
        }
    };
});
```

You have created isolated scope for you test directive and you are assigning value of data variable to your test directive's `$scope.value`.
Directive is compiling only once so once it compiles it will bind the value after than any change in parent scope's variable is not affecting here because you created isolated scope and copied value from parent's scope.

For better understanding of directive check out this article

- [directive life cycle](http://filimanjaro.com/blog/2014/angular-directive-lifecycle-vs-link-compile-controller/)
- [Compile, Pre, and Post Linking in AngularJS](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/28/compile-pre-and-post-linking-in-angularjs.aspx)

Comment: But that's exactly my problem, I need to have some variables only inside the scope of directive, for the plunker I assigned a value from the array, but the problem persists for any value inside the scope of the directive. Since this problem doesn't happen if I don't use the track by index, I believe I'm missing something.

Comment: In that case your are directly removing from array so ng-repeat is again iterating list and directive is compiling again due to that so in that result is as per your expectation.

Comment: Directives only compile one time, and that's what's happening, otherwise the values would be correct.

Comment: While you are performing without index at that time ng-repeat is iteration again with modified array so it is working fine.

Comment: I believe the problem is that by using track by index, angular will reuse nodes. Since I need duplicated values in the list I will need to create a "unique" id and do the tracking by that.

Comment: @JoãoAugusto You beauty! You are the only person to have found this! I've been looking all day! Using a real unique identifier that is not $index fixed our issue!

Answer (score 0):

> using track by index, angular will reuse nodes

This is effectively the issue; the directive is not reinitialised as Angular seems ignore it's value parameters and keep the original data from the index.

E.g.

```
var arr = [
  { id: 0, status: "Pass" },
  { id: 1, status: "Fail" }
];
```

If you repeat this data and have a custom directive in the repeat that would display a green dot for pass and a red dot for fail.

Example: https://plnkr.co/edit/ytQ9p6YJOfrDubCGIc2N?p=preview

```css
.pass {
  color: green;
}

.fail {
  color: red
}

.pass,
.fail {
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>Status</th>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="pass">&squf;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td class="fail">&squf;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When applying a filter e.g. via $filter on `arr` that filters out the the object with ID:1

```css
.pass {
  color: green;
}

.fail {
  color: red
}

.pass,
.fail {
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>Status</th>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td class="pass">&squf;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see, 1 was filtered out, but the result is now incorrect. This is because Angular is being a little lazy and not reinitialising the directive that we are using even though the data we passed in is now different.